# How to sign text file, or any other than xml

Tags: c#, x509certificate

How do I sign an file which contains regular text?

I am explaining right away.
I created an app in C# which lets you sign an XML document, using certificate on USB token. I select a certificate from collection:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlString);
X509Certificate2 myCert = null;
X509Store st = new X509Store();
st.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
X509Certificate2Collection collection = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(st.Certificates, "Choose certificate:", "", X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
```

And then I use everything I got so far, to sign this xml document:

```
public static string SignXmlWithCertificate(XmlDocument Document, X509Certificate2 cert)
    {
        SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(Document);
        // pure black magic
        signedXml.SigningKey = cert.PrivateKey;

        // Create a reference to be signed.
        Reference reference = new Reference();
        reference.Uri = "";

        // Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.           
        XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env =
           new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform(true);
        reference.AddTransform(env);

        //canonicalize
        XmlDsigC14NTransform c14t = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
        reference.AddTransform(c14t);

        KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
        KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoData = new KeyInfoX509Data(cert);
        KeyInfoName kin = new KeyInfoName();
        kin.Value = "Public key of certificate";
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaprovider = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PublicKey.Key;
        RSAKeyValue rkv = new RSAKeyValue(rsaprovider);
        keyInfo.AddClause(kin);
        keyInfo.AddClause(rkv);
        keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoData);
        signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

        // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
        signedXml.AddReference(reference);

        // Compute the signature.
        signedXml.ComputeSignature();

        // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
        // it to an XmlElement object.
        XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

        Document.DocumentElement.AppendChild(
            Document.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

        return Document.OuterXml;
    }
```

**Actual question**
My question is, how to do the same, with just plain text file. I mean when I use signing software, I can see pretty much same file, except that text (instead of xml) is encoded in base64.
What methods do I use in C# to sign regular file? I can't load it to `XmlDocument` because it's just not an XML.

I know you are going to ask anyway, so yes. I've tried finding it in google, but I guess I am just using wrong words to search for it. So any help appreciated.

Comment: See if this helps: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/alejacma/2008/06/25/how-to-sign-and-verify-the-signature-with-net-and-a-certificate-c/

Answer (score 0):

In order to sign the file with digital signature, there must be a schema that can be used to distinguish file data and signature block. For example, script text files (say, .ps1, .vbs, .js, etc.) have such schema, where signature is placed in the comment block at the end of file. Similar approach is used in complex document types, .pdf, .docx, etc.

Since, text files doesn't have such schema, you will have to introduce new file type and define rules that would define file content and signature structures.

If you cannot enforce rules to text files, you can use catalog signing. In this case, you put text file hashes in the catalog file (.cat) and digitally sign it.

Answer (score -4):

You can sign a .txt from within MS word and Open Office. Exact method will depend on the version that you use.

Comment: Well, sorry but what does MS word or Open Office has to do with C# application? If i wanted to do it only once, I could use software provided with USB  token/certificate. But i am trying to create an application to do it over and over again.